# Installing GDAL with ECW support

Tags: gdal

Most (all?) information online is outdated since ECW (Hexagon Geospatial/Intergraph) has recently released new versions with breaking changes (5.0, 5.1 and 5.2).

Most instructions result in errors like:

> checking for libNCSEcw.so or libecwj2... configure: error: not found in /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for GDAL 1.11.2, but it should work back to 1.10.0.

Download the latest version of the ECW library from here (currently 5.5):
https://download.hexagongeospatial.com

Instructions for v5.2.1, but should be similar for the latest version:

```
$ unzip erdas-ecwjp2sdk-v5.2.1-linux.zip
$ chmod +x ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.2.1.bin
$ ./ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.2.1.bin
```

Choose Desktop Read-Only and accept the license. A directory named `hexagon` is extracted. Copy that to `/usr/local`.

```
$ sudo cp -r hexagon/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.2.1/Desktop_Read-Only /usr/local/hexagon
```

Link the `.so` library for the correct architecture:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/hexagon/lib/(x64|x86)/release/libNCSEcw.so /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so
```

Then configure GDAL with this command:

```
$ ./configure --with-ecw=/usr/local/hexagon
```

Comment: thank you. But where do I run the last command from (configure GDAL)?

Comment: You have to install GDAL from source. You run configure in the untar-ed source directory

Comment: configured, installed gdal 2.0.0 from source, but still getting ERROR 4: `map.ecw' not recognised as a supported file format.

Comment: When you run ./configure, do you see ECW support: yes?

Comment: And if you run `gdal-config --formats` is ecw listed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87017/discussion-between-eagor-and-nathancahill).

Comment: Download link is dead.

Comment: Thanks @Rabbit, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Before I could see ECW support in `gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw`
I also had to run `sudo ldconfig`.
That was in Ubuntu 14.04 Linux.